# Load Product Qty by sku in Magento 2 Controller

Tags: magento2, quantity, sku

```
public function execute()
{
    // Product Colletion 
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'special_price', 'entity_id']);
    $productColl = [];
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        // check simple products only
        if ($product->getTypeId() == 'simple') {

            $productX = $this->_productRepository->get($product->getSku());
            $stockItem = $productX->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
            $qty = $stockItem->getQty();
            print_r($qty);

            $sku = $product->getSku();
            // code for Qty

        }
    }
}
```

How to get product Qty using SKU In Controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First load product by sku:

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
```

To get stock qty use this:

```
$StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
```

Where `$stockState` is the instance of `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface`

Answer (score 3):

Get the quantity by using the following code

```
 protected $_stockRepository;

 protected $_product;

 public function __construct(
   Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockRepository,
   Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 ) {
    $this->_stockRepository= $stockItem;
    $this->_product = $product;
 }
```

And use like this

```
$productId=$this->_product->getIdBySku('Product_SKU');
if($productId){
$productStock = $this->_stockRepository->get($productId);
$productQty = $productStock->getQty();
}
```